# Get the angle degrees from 2 points on a grid

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, angle

I have a grid for a flat, 2D map which is a bit different from usual. The top left point is 0,0 and bottom right is 1000,1000. I have 2 points on this map, an origin/anchor point and a destination.

I am looking to figure out the degrees (in javascript) from the origin to the destination. I have looked through many answers and they all don't produce the correct result.

```
function getAngle(origin_x, origin_y, destination_x, destination_y) {
var newx = destination_x - origin_x;
var newy = destination_y - origin_y;
var theta = Math.atan2(-newy, newx);
if (theta < 0) {
theta += 2 * Math.PI;
}
theta *= 180 / Math.PI;
return theta;
}
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't produce the right angle.

[image: Image of the problem]

Thankyou very much in advance!

Comment: An angle needs two supporting lines to be measured. Where is your second one? Is it the x-axis / y-axis? Can you show a figure of which angle you want to calculate?

Comment: @NicoSchertler its going to become a cardinal direction. So its just from a north line coming out of the origin, to the destination.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Ive now included a diagram. Thanks

Comment: Is the north direction `(0, -1)`? Then, `atan2(newx, -newy)` should do. If this is not what you want, can you provide some example directions with the angles you want?

Comment: @NicoSchertler this little change seems to have fixed it! Thankyou!

Comment: @nico. It works for 4-neighbor grid map and appreciated your answer. I was trying for 8 neighbours 2D grid map from 3days. But i am not getting the exact result of it. For example a map image is https://ibb.co/6FNTWww

Comment: @milton Please post a new question with some more details. Angle calculation does not depend on neighbor connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

[image from mdn Math.atan2 doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqTOk.png)

It will give the angle relative to the x-axis, not the y-axis. To convert all you would do is

var newAngle = 90 - theta;

Comment: Thankyou very much!

Comment: @JeremyBen if you believe this answers your question you should give credit for it.

Comment: @PhilipBrack Nico's comment answered the question